# Does hard restart of agent delete data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

Does hard restart of agent delete data?

I did a hard restart of my agent and now I do not see data in `hadoop fs -ls /user/hue` or `hadoop fs -ls /user/hive` where did it go? I also do not see my other users but only hue and hive. What do I do? Where did it go?

I don't think data in hdfs should go anywhere with that.

If I query my tables in hive, I keep getting

```
The operation has no results
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a hard restart of the Cloudera Manager agent will not cause data loss, but will cause all of the Hadoop daemons to be restarted. A normal restart of the agent does not do this, so a hard restart is useful if you need to force a stop of all the running processes.

If you are seeing no data in HDFS following a restart check the status of the HDFS service in Cloudera Manager. It will tell you how much capacity is used in HDFS, the number of files and other metrics. If you're seeing no data it could be that your DataNodes have not been started. Check to see if this is the case and if your NameNode is still in safe mode.